# server busy error message vb.net

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, switch-statement

I get this error. I can not catch it where it comes from. All methods made with try catch but still I get this error from time to time. I used code:

```
    Private Sub add2ComboBox_called(ByVal text As String)
    Try
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim args() As String = {text}
            Me.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf add2ComboBox_called), args)
            Return
        End If
        ComboBox_called.Items.Add(text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        log_it(ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub
```

and also this one:

```
Public Sub clear_do_not_open()
    Dim FILENAME As String = path & "\DO_NOT.OPEN"
    Dim index As Integer
    Try
        Using fs As New IO.FileStream(FILENAME, IO.FileMode.Truncate, IO.FileAccess.Write, IO.FileShare.ReadWrite), _
              tl As New TextWriterTraceListener(fs)
            index = Trace.Listeners.Add(tl)
            Trace.Write("")
            Trace.Listeners(index).Flush()
            Trace.Flush()
        End Using
        Trace.Listeners.RemoveAt(index)
    Catch ex As Exception
        log_it(ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub
```

How do I make this to press Retry by default if it appears? Wait for a second and press Retry again? If not like this then how do I know that this message pops up? If catch the moment it shows up I could then just restart the program or send an email to myselt so I could come to PC where program runs and I could handle it. Now message pops up and program stops while its on.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you are locking up your program. Rather work to not lock it up, than to try and "click" a button when it does lock up?

Comment: How do I catch the moment it appears? I am not by this PC while program runs so I cannot to see when it stops/waits to click it.

Comment: It looks you are creating threads.. Maybe your not doing it quite right...? Don't catch anything, re-think your threading model?

Comment: I am using alcatel agent library, creating object and working with it, so I guess sometimes this agent just locks up while talking to server and becomes busy for unknown reason to me, so I just want to catch this message.

Comment: Thats not a message produced by your code. That is a windows message. Fire the remote function off in a new thread?

Comment: Not quite understand but what would be the solution for this problem?

Comment: It is really important for me and big pain in a...

Comment: You will have to put in some effort sir.. I cant exactly do it for you, I can only make a suggestion. As suggested, create a new thread for the code that calls the Remote Alcatel procedures... Do a searhc in google for "vb.net create new thread"